# Authorize attribute being ignored even if logged in

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

It seems as if the action decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute gets ignored even if I'm logged in.
it's probably not being *ignored* it's more so that I probably routed things incorrectly.

So in my `Home` controller I have the default `Privacy` page and I've decorated the action in the `HomeController` like so

```cs
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}
```

And if I'm not logged in it's going to redirect me to `/signin` when I try to access `/privacy`
I then go ahead and login and I try to access that page after a successful login, but it just redirects me to `/signin` again

This is what my `ConfigureServices` looks like.. Did I forget something?

```cs
//Add identity
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    config.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
    config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AccountDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();


services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
{
    config.Cookie.Name = "Identity.Cookie";
    config.LoginPath = "/signin";
}
```

This is the `Signin`

```
[Route("signin")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Signin(SigninUserModel userModel)
{
    var user = new IdentityUser
    {
        UserName = userModel.Username,
        PasswordHash = userModel.Password
    };

    if (userManager.FindByNameAsync(userModel.Username).Result != null)
    {
        var result = await signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userModel.Username,
                                            userModel.Password,
                                            isPersistent: false,
                                            lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            //Return the user to the dashboard.
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Uh oh! It seems as if that's not the correct password.");
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Uh oh! Couldn't find an account with that username.");
        return View();
    }

    
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Could you share `Configure` method in Startup.cs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the order of your middlewares would be incorrect in `Configure` method. They must be called in the following order:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

[More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services)